# AL MOMENTO DE CAMBIAR LOS ESTADOS DE ACTIVO A INACTIVO NO SE VISUALIZAN LOS CAMBIOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo un problema la momento de cambiar los estado de activo a inactivo se me cambia en la vista pero en la base de datos no se me cambia sigue estando activo, solo tengo ese problema, aquí debajo pongo a disposición el código fuente de ese apartado.

[image: IMAGEN 1 ACTIVO EN BD]
[image: IMAGEN 2 VISTAS ACTIVOS]
[image: VISTA INACTIVOS]
[image: SIGUEN ACTIVOS AUNQUE YA EN LA VISTA ESTAN INACTIVOS]
..........................................................................................................................................................................
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="_recursos/js/consola_personal.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_recursos/input-file/css/diseño_input_2.css">
<script src="_recursos/input-file/js/bootstrap-uploader/file-upload.js"></script>
<div class="contendor_kn">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2><b>PERSONAL REGISTRADO</b></h2>            
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <br>
     <div class="col-md-10"> 
         <div class=" input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el documento de identidad nacional" id="txtbuscar_personal"  onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)"  >
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <button style="width:100%" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cargar_contenido('main-content','Personal/vista_registrar_personal.php')"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;<b>Nuevo Registro</b></button></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive" style="text-align: center;">
             <br>
             <label>LISTADO DEL PERSONAL ADMINISTRATIVO</label>
                <div id="lista_personal_tabla" class="icon-loading">
                </div>
                <p id="paginador_personal_tabla" style="text-align:right" class="mi_paginador"></p>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- INICIO MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="modal_editar_personal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Editar Personal</b></h4>
         </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                         <input type="text" id="txtidciudadano" hidden >
                         <label>Nombres </label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" id="txtnombre_alimentos" placeholder="Ingrese Nombres" maxlength="">
                         <br>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label>Apellido Paterno </label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control"onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"id="txtapellidopaterno" placeholder="Ingrese Apellido Paterno" maxlength="">
                        <br>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label >Apellido Materno </label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" id="txtapellidomaterno" placeholder="Ingrese Apelido Materno" maxlength="">
                         <br>
                     </div> 
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <label >Tel&eacute;fono </label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" id="txttelefono_modal" placeholder="Ingrese nro telefóno" maxlength="9">
                         <br>
                     </div>        
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label>Movil </label>
                         <input type="text"class="form-control" id="txtmovil_modal"  onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" placeholder="Ingrese nro movil" maxlength="9">
                             <br>
                     </div> 
                     <div class="col-md-8">
                         <label>Direcci&oacute;n </label>
                         <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="txtdireccion_modal" placeholder="Ingrese dirección" maxlength="200">
                         <br>
                     </div> 
                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <label>Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                         <div class=" input-group">
                           <div class="input-group-addon">
                             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                           </div>
                           <input type="date" style="padding: 0px 12px;background-color: #FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" id="txtfecha_modal"  class="form-control"  >
                         </div><br>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                         <label>Nro Documento</label>
                         <input type="text"  class="form-control"  onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" id="txtnrodocumento" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Ingrese nro Documento" maxlength="8">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <label>Email</label>
                         <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="txtemail_modal" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Ingrese nro Documento" maxlength="80">
                     </div> 
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label>Estado</label>
             <select id="cmb_estadopersonal" style="width: 100%" class="form-control select2">
                <option value="ACTIVO">ACTIVO</option>
                <option value="INACTIVO">INACTIVO</option>
             </select>
                     </div>  
   </div>         
        </div> 
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button  class="btn btn-success" onclick="Editar_personal()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;<b>Modificar Personal</b></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>&nbsp;<b>Cancelar</b></button>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
<style type="text/css">
 .contendor_kn{
  padding: 10px;
 }
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript">listar_personal_vista('','1');</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#txtbuscar_personal").keyup(function(){
    var dato_buscar = $("#txtbuscar_personal").val();
    listar_personal_vista(dato_buscar,'1');
  });
</script>
<script>
    function soloLetras(e){
       key = e.keyCode || e.which;
       tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
       letras = " áéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
       especiales = "8-37-39-46";

       tecla_especial = false
       for(var i in especiales){
            if(key == especiales[i]){
                tecla_especial = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(letras.indexOf(tecla)==-1 && !tecla_especial){
            return false;
        }
    }
   function soloNumeros(e){
       tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
     if (tecla==8){
          return true;
     }  
      // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros
       patron =/[0-9]/;
       tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
       return patron.test(tecla_final);
   }
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.select2').select2();
    })
</script>
```

PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO!

```html
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PA_VERIFICARUSUARIO`(IN `_usu` VARCHAR(30), IN `_pass` VARCHAR(30))
SELECT
usuario.usu_nombre,
usuario.usu_clave,
CONCAT_WS(' ',personal.pers_nombres,personal.pers_apellidoPate,personal.pers_apellidoMate),

tipo_usuario.cod_tipousuario,
usuario.usu_foto,
personal.personal_cod,
tipo_usuario.tipusu_descripcion,
usuario.cod_usuario,
usuario.usu_estado
FROM
personal
INNER JOIN usuario ON personal.usuario_cod = usuario.cod_usuario
INNER JOIN tipo_usuario ON usuario.cod_tipousuario = tipo_usuario.cod_tipousuario
WHERE usuario.usu_nombre = _usu AND usuario.usu_clave = _pass
```

CONSOLA PERSONAL

```html
function Limpieza_post_personal(){
 $("#txtPersonaNombre").val("");
 $("#txtApellidoPaterno").val("");
 $("#txtApellidoMaterno").val("");
 $("#txtDireccion").val(""); 
 $("#txtDNI").val("");
 $("#txtGenero").val("");
 $("#txtFechaNacimiento").val("");
 $("#txtDistrito").val(""); 
 $("#txtProvincia").val(""); 
 $("#txtDepartamento").val("");
 $("#txtDireccion").val("");
 $("#txtTelefono").val("");
 $("#txtEmail").val("");
 $("#combo_TipoPersonal").val(1);
 $('#id_archivo_Fotografia').fileinput('reset');
 $("#main-content").load("Personal/vista_listar_personal.php") 
}
function listar_personal_vista(valor,pagina){
 var pagina = Number(pagina);
 $.ajax({
  url:'../controlador/personal/controlador_ListarBuscar_personal.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data:'valor='+valor+'&pagina='+pagina+'&boton=buscar',
  beforeSend: function(){
   $("#loading_almacen").addClass("fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw");
  },
     complete: function(){
       $("#loading_almacen").removeClass("fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw");
     },
  success: function(resp){
   var datos = resp.split("*"); 
   var valores = eval(datos[0]); 
   if(valores.length>0){
    var cadena = "";
    cadena += "<table  class='table table-condensed jambo_table'>";
    cadena += "<thead  class=''>";
    cadena += "<tr >";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center' hidden='true' >ID</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>NOMBRE Y APELLIDOS</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>DNI</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>SEXO</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>FECHA NACIMIENTO</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>PUESTO</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>USUARIO</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>ESTADO</th>";
    cadena += "<th>ACCI&Oacute;N</th>";
    cadena += "</tr>";
    cadena += "</thead>";
    cadena += "<tbody>";
    for(var i = 0 ; i<valores.length; i++){
     cadena += "<tr>";   
     cadena += "<td align='center' hidden>"+valores[i][0]+"</td>";
     cadena += "<td>"+valores[i][1]+" "+valores[i][2]+" "+valores[i][3]+"</td>";
     cadena += "<td align='center'>"+valores[i][4]+"</td>";
     cadena += "<td align='center'>"+valores[i][5]+"</td>";
     cadena += "<td align='center'>"+valores[i][6]+"</td>";
     cadena += "<td style='color:#9B0000; text-align:center;font-weight: bold;'>"+valores[i][14]+"</td>";
     cadena += "<td style='color:#9B0000; text-align:center;font-weight: bold;'>"+valores[i][13]+"</td>";
     if (valores[i][12]=="INACTIVO") {
      cadena += "<td style = 'text-align: center'> <span class='badge bg-danger' style='color:White;'>"+valores[i][12]+"</span> </td>";
     }else{
      cadena += "<td  style = 'text-align: center'> <span class='badge bg-success' style='color:White;'>"+valores[i][12]+"</span> </td>";
     }
     cadena += "<td><button name='"+valores[i][0]+"*"+valores[i][1]+"*"+valores[i][2]+"*"+valores[i][3]+"*"+valores[i][4]+"*"+valores[i][5]+"*"+valores[i][6]+"*"+valores[i][7]+"*"+valores[i][8]+"*"+valores[i][9]+"*"+valores[i][10]+"*"+valores[i][11]+"*"+valores[i][12]+"*"+valores[i][13]+"*"+valores[i][14]+"' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='AbrirModalEditarPersonal(this)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>";
     cadena += "</button></td> ";
     cadena += "</tr>";
    }
    cadena += "</tbody>";
    cadena += "</table>";
    $("#lista_personal_tabla").html(cadena);
    var totaldatos = datos[1];
    var numero_paginas = Math.ceil(totaldatos/5); 
    var paginar = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    if(pagina>1){
     paginar += "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='listar_personal_vista("+'"'+valor+'","'+1+'"'+")'>&laquo;</a></li>";
     paginar += "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='listar_personal_vista("+'"'+valor+'","'+(pagina-1)+'"'+")'>Anterior</a></li>";
    }
    else{
     paginar += "<li class='disabled'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>&laquo;</a></li>";
     paginar += "<li class='disabled'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Anterior</a></li>";
    }
    limite = 10;
    div = Math.ceil(limite/2);
    pagina_inicio = (pagina > div) ? (pagina - div):1;
    if(numero_paginas > div){
     pagina_restante = numero_paginas - pagina;
     pagina_fin = (pagina_restante > div) ? (pagina + div) : numero_paginas;
    }
    else{
     pagina_fin = numero_paginas;
    }
    for(i = pagina_inicio;i<=pagina_fin;i++){
     if(i==pagina){
      paginar +="<li class='active'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>"+i+"</a></li>";
     }
     else{
      paginar += "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='listar_personal_vista("+'"'+valor+'","'+i+'"'+")'>"+i+"</a></li>";
     }
    }
    if(pagina < numero_paginas){
     paginar += "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='listar_personal_vista("+'"'+valor+'","'+(pagina+1)+'"'+")'>Siguiente</a></li>";
     paginar += "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='listar_personal_vista("+'"'+valor+'","'+numero_paginas+'"'+")'>&raquo;</a></li>";
    }
    else{
     paginar += "<li class='disabled'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Siguiente</a></li>";
     paginar += "<li class='disabled'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>&raquo;</a></li>";
    }
    paginar += "</ul>";
    $("#paginador_personal_tabla").html(paginar);
   }else{
    var cadena = "";
    cadena += "<table  class='table table-condensed jambo_table'>";
    cadena += "<thead  class=''>";
    cadena += "<tr >";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center' hidden='true' >ID</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>NOMBRE Y APELLIDOS</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>DNI</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>SEXO</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>FECHA NACIMIENTO</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>USUARIO</th>";
    cadena += "<th style = 'text-align: center'>ESTADO</th>";
    cadena += "<th>ACCI&Oacute;N</th>";
    cadena += "</tr>";
    cadena += "</thead>";
    cadena += "<tbody>";
    cadena +="<tr style = 'text-align: center'><td colspan='8'><strong>No se encontraron registros</strong></td></tr>";
    cadena += "</tbody>";
    cadena += "</table>";
    $("#lista_personal_tabla").html(cadena);
    $("#paginador_personal_tabla").html("");
   }
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR){
   alert("SE PRODUJO UN ERROR");
  }
 });
}
function AbrirModalEditarPersonal(control){
 var datos = control.name;
 var datos_split = datos.split("*");
 $("#modal_editar_personal").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
 $("#modal_editar_personal").modal('show');
 $("#txtidciudadano").val(datos_split[0]);
 $("#txtnombre_alimentos").val(datos_split[1]);
 $("#txtapellidopaterno").val(datos_split[2]);
 $("#txtapellidomaterno").val(datos_split[3]);
 $("#txtemail_modal").val(datos_split[10]);
 $("#txtnrodocumento").val(datos_split[4]);
 $("#txttelefono_modal").val(datos_split[8]);
 $("#txtmovil_modal").val(datos_split[9]);
 $("#txtdireccion_modal").val(datos_split[7]);
 $("#txtfecha_modal").val(datos_split[6]); 
 $("#cmb_estadopersonal").val(datos_split[12]).trigger("change"); 
}
function Editar_personal(){
 var codigo    = $("#txtidciudadano").val();
 var nombre    = $("#txtnombre_alimentos").val();
 var apepat    = $("#txtapellidopaterno").val();
 var apemat    = $("#txtapellidomaterno").val();
 var telefono  = $("#txttelefono_modal").val();
 var movil     = $("#txtmovil_modal").val();
 var direccion = $("#txtdireccion_modal").val();
 var fecha     = $("#txtfecha_modal").val();
 var nrodocume = $("#txtnrodocumento").val();
 var email     = $("#txtemail_modal").val();
 var estado    = $("#cmb_estadopersonal").val();
 if(nombre.length>0 && apepat.length>0 && apemat.length>0 && direccion.length>0 && nrodocume.length>0 && email.length>0 ){
 }
 else{
  return swal("Falta Llenar Datos", "", "info"); 
 } 
 $.ajax({
  url:'../controlador/personal/controlador_editar_personal.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{
  codigo:codigo,
  nombre:nombre,
  apepat:apepat,  
  apemat:apemat,
  telefono:telefono, 
  movil:movil,
  direccion:direccion,
  fecha:fecha,
  nrodocume:nrodocume,
  email:email,
  estado:estado
  }
 })
 .done(function(resp){
 

  if (resp > 0) {
   $("#modal_editar_personal").modal('hide');
    swal("Datos Actualizados!", "", "success");
    var dato_buscar = $("#txtbuscar_personal").val();
     listar_personal_vista(dato_buscar,'1');
  }
  else{
   swal("! Registro no completado!", "", "error"); 
  }
 })
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

     alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

   } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

     alert('Requested page not found [404]');

   } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

     alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

   } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

     alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

   } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

     alert('Time out error.');

   } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

     alert('Ajax request aborted.');

   } else {

     alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

   }
 })   
}
function revisar_dni_personal(){
 var nombre    = $("#txtnombre").val();
 var apepat    = $("#txtapellidopaterno").val();
 var apemat    = $("#txtapellidomaterno").val();
 var fecha     = $("#txtfecha").val();
 var direccion = $("#txtdireccion").val();
 var dni       = $("#txtdni").val();
 var sexo      = $("#txtGenero").val();
 var email     = $("#txtemail").val();
 var telefono  = $("#txttelefono").val();
 var movil     = $("#txtmovil").val();
 var usuario   = $("#txtusuario").val();
 var clave     = $("#txtclave").val();
 var tipo      = $("#cmbTipousuario").val();
 var puesto    = $("#txtpuesto").val();
 
 if (nombre.length>0  && apemat.length>0 && apepat.length>0 && fecha.length>0 && direccion.length>0 ) {
 }else{
  return swal("Faltan Llenar Datos","","info");
 }
 if (dni.length==0 ) {
  return swal("Faltan Llenar Su Documento de Identidad","","info");
 }
 if (usuario.length==0) {
  return swal("Faltan Llenar Su usuario","","info");
 }
 if (clave.length==0) {
  return swal("Faltan Llenar Su Clave","","info");
 }
 if (tipo=='otro') {
  return swal("Falta Seleccionar el Tipo de usuario","","error");
 }
 $.ajax({
  url:'../controlador/ciudadano/controlador_verificar_existencia_dni.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{
   dni:dni
  }
 })
 .done(function(resp){
  var data = JSON.parse(resp);
  if (data.length<=0) {
   Registrar_personal();
   
  }else{
   swal("Lo sentimos el DNI Ingresado ya esta siendo utilizado por otro personal","","warning");
  }
 })
}
function Registrar_personal(){
 var nombre    = $("#txtnombre").val();
 var apepat    = $("#txtapellidopaterno").val();
 var apemat    = $("#txtapellidomaterno").val();
 var fecha     = $("#txtfecha").val();
 var direccion = $("#txtdireccion").val();
 var dni       = $("#txtdni").val();
 var sexo      = $("#txtGenero").val();
 var email     = $("#txtemail").val();
 var telefono  = $("#txttelefono").val();
 var movil     = $("#txtmovil").val();
 var usuario   = $("#txtusuario").val();
 var clave     = $("#txtclave").val();
 var tipo      = $("#cmbTipousuario").val();
 var puesto    = $("#txtpuesto").val();
 if (tipo=='otro') {
  return swal("Falta Seleccionar el Tipo de usuario","","error");
 }
 $.ajax({
  url:'../controlador/personal/controlador_registrar_personal.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{
   nombre:nombre,
   apepat:apepat,  
   apemat:apemat,
   telefono:telefono, 
   movil:movil,
   direccion:direccion,
   fecha:fecha,
   nrodocume:dni,
   email:email,
   sexo:sexo,
   usuario:usuario,
   clave:clave,
   tipo:tipo,
   puesto:puesto
  }
 })
 .done(function(resp){
  if (resp > 0) {
    swal("Datos Registrados!", "", "success")
    .then ( ( value ) =>  { 
      $("#main-content").load("Personal/vista_listar_personal.php"); 
   });
   
  }
  else{
   swal("! Registro no completado!", "", "error"); 
  }
 })  
}
function Listar_tipousuario_combo() {
 $.ajax({
  url:'../controlador/personal/controlador_combolistar_tipousuario.php',
  type:'POST'
 })
 .done(function(resp) {
  var data = JSON.parse(resp);
  if (data.length > 0) {
   var cadena = "";
    cadena += "<option value='otro'>"+"SELECCIONAR TIPO USUARIO"+"</option>";
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cadena += "<option value='"+data[i][0]+"'>"+data[i][1]+"</option>";
   }
   $("#cmbTipousuario").html(cadena); 
  }
  else{
   var cadena = "<option value='NO'>no se encontraron tipo de usuario Disponibles</option>";
   $("#cmbTipousuario").html(cadena);
  }
 })
}
```

Comment: Y donde esta la consulta que hace el cambio en la base de datos?

Comment: ACABO DE PONER LA CONSULTA  AMIGO!!

Comment: Pero esa es la consulta para mostrar los resultados, no la consulta para actualizar los datos del usuarios. Tendrá que ser o un update, o un delete y luego un insert. Haría falta también el código PHP que ejecuta esa o esas consultas.

Comment: Sabes que escribir en mayusculas es como gritar no? trata de evitarlo. En donde esta la parte que actualiza la base de datos con los cambios que haces en la pantalla?

Comment: gracias por el consejo amigo.... lo actualizo usando javascript

Comment: Ya te dieron el consejo de mayúsculas == gritar. Ya agradeciste por ello, ahora ¿podrías editar la pregunta, por favor?

Comment: Si pero tu javascript, es una función ajax, que manda llamar un PHP, el cual tiene un consulta en MYSQL, que actualiza -> cual es esa consulta de mysql